# Delete content of contenteditable div, add strange font element

Tags: javascript, fonts, contenteditable, html

I have a problem with a contenteditable div.

The div start with a span with a style, but when i delete content and write appear a new element font, with same font but with size converted, 24 to 5.

What is the problem? How can i set span??

I make an example, see the console log when you delete all from content editable and write...

http://jsfiddle.net/bVvxp/

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="test">
        <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;">Hello!!!</span>
</div>
```

P.S.
Sorry for my bad school english and thanks to all!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the font properties to the parent element of the span (in your case #test).
If you do that, you don't have to specify font properties in span either; they will simply be inherited.
So just change this CSS rule in your fiddle

```
#test{width:300px; height:200px; background-color:black; color:white;}
```

to

```
#test{width:300px; height:200px; background-color:black; color:white; font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;}
```

If you want to target only specific child elements like  in your #test div, you can add such a CSS line:

```
#test span {font-family:Arial;font-size:24px;}
```

**EDIT:** The reason why your problem occurred: When you remove 'Hello!!!' from #test, the span is removed as well, removing all font-styling. That's why you have to put the font-styling on #test. I re-edited the fiddle, and you'll see that every time you mouseout of #test, your font-size stays the same; and #test has no child elements. http://jsfiddle.net/bVvxp/4/

Comment: Edited my answer, hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks, but i can't set style on the div parent.

Comment: I know that the span is deleted, but WHY only chrome add a deprecated font element instead the text alone??? Can i fix this?

Comment: A quick google search revealed that this is a bug within Google Chrome. <FONT> tags are deprecated anyway, so that's kind of weird. I made a last jsfiddle update completely working, with the css applied only to the span. http://jsfiddle.net/bVvxp/6/ . The <FONT> tag doesn't appear when #test is empty, and the #test div returns undefined for font-size.

Comment: Thanks, it's CRACY, the same problem is on Safari, is the WEBKit the problem, i try with this solution in my project, hoping to solve the problem!